# Calling one module into another if both modules are in diffrent directories

Tags: python

I have two python modules on below location :

> /abc/main_menu.py
>
> /xyz/first.py

where as in main_menu.py I have some function :

```
def print_menu():
        print " "
        print bcolors.OKBLUE + '\t\t\t\t' + (52 * '*') + bcolors.OKBLUE
        print ("\t\t\t\t\t\tM A I N - M E N U")
        print '\t\t\t\t' + (52 * '*')
        print ("\t\t\t\t 0. Enter List Name(s).")
        print ("\t\t\t\t 1. Check List Connectivity.")
        print ("\t\t\t\t 2. Set All Lists.")
        print ("\t\t\t\t 3. Remove All Lists.")
        print ("\t\t\t\t 4. Set Blackouts on Lists.")
        print ("\t\t\t\t 5. Check Blackout Status.")
        print ("\t\t\t\t 10. To Use first module.")

def List():
        # Do some stuff
        # Do some stuff

def status():
        # Do some stuff
        # Do some stuff

def connectivity():
        # Do some stuff
        # Do some stuff


while choice >= 0 and choice < 5:
        if choice == 0:
            List()
        if choice == 1:
            connectivity()
        if choice == 5:
            status()
```

I want first.py file to be called in main_menu.py where first.py file is having some other functions.
I need to call /xyz/first.py module in /abc/main_menu.py while introducing 10th option main /abc/main_menu.py module. As you seeing in above code from main_menu.py I have given 10th option as :

**print ("\t\t\t\t 10. To Use first module.")**

The question is : how can I call first module by this way?

Comment: I have resoled this by calling first.py like : 
if choice == 10:
     os.system('python /xyz/first.py')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the folder from which you want to import to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/xyz')
import first
# eventually in you want to clean sys.path after the import
sys.path.remove('/xyz')
```

But you do not really want to do that: it is not *pythonic*. The correct way is to put all modules that can be used by other modules in some folders, and register those folders in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. That allows to write portable scripts.

The alternative if you are multiple modules that are used in one single application (or constitute a library) is to organize them into a [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).